# Updating a nuget package whenever one of it's dependencies are changed?

Tags: architecture, nuget

We have a huge project and we have decided to break everything that is standalone into reusable Nugets.

The project is in mid phase development.

We have multiple processes like: Services, Business Processes, Clients etc. The different processes use shared Nugets such as: Infrastructural, Logic Engines, DB, File managers etc.

I have two questions:

1. When updating a low level Nuget, is it correct to create Nugets for
   all the above dependent Nugets like a pyramid? An automatic tool
   that will detect the change and raise versions to all dependent
   Nugets perhaps? Is there any tool that does that automatically?
2. When changing bugs on a low or mid level Nugget, and API was not
   broken, is it a good practice to update the new version all over the system? For validation, verification and stability purposes?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Here is an example to clarify my question:

If **NugetA.ver1.0.0** is being upgraded to ver 1.0.1, is it best to create **NugetAB.ver1.01** and **NugetABC.ver1.0.1** as well?

Bear in mind that there are many suits like this one in the system, **NugetA** could be a logger package or a Math library that many modules are dependent on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many viewpoints on this, but I think a very nice discussion that should be read is provided here: [Version after dependency change](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/148)

Another point to keep in mind, no matter what you choose, is that having too many too granular packages should be generally avoided.

Comment: Thanks @Denis Biondic. The discussion link you have added is interesting. I have edited my question to clarify my meaning.